# How to upload file to FTP Server in grails

Tags: grails

I've read the answers to the question asked here :
[How to upload file to remote FTP Server in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587155/how-to-upload-file-to-remote-ftp-server-in-grails/36602484#36602484)

everything compiles and runs without errors. Now how do I reference the upload service from a Grails form? Sorry for the basic question.

So far I'm playing around with

```
          <g:form action="do_something" enctype="multipart/form-data" useToken="true">

            <span class="button">                   
            <input type="file" name="thefile"/>
            <input type="submit" class="upload" value="upload"/>

            </span>

          </g:form>
```

but I just need a few pointers as to how to link this with the service, presumably via the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work with the request. Get the file name and create a new file. my own code:

```
def f = request.getFile('myfile'); 
def webrootDir = servletContext.getRealPath("/"); //app directory 
File fileDest = new File(webrootDir,"xmls/"); 
def xmlFile = new File(fileDest, "settings.xml"); 
f.transferTo(xmlFile);
```

Just look [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519144/how-to-upload-file-into-server-directory-with-grails) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. This helps, and I can now upload files, but I'm having problems with filenames. If I follow the post you signposted me to, the filename of the file I'm uploading ends up as  'some_folder' and it is in the images directory.  I create the folder images/some_folder but it just overwrites the folder some_folder with the actual file.  So I end up with a file in the images folder, and the file is called some_folder.  What I want is to put the file into some_folder with the filename of the file I'm uploading.

Comment: Are you sure you did everything correctly? That post shows that you create a directory and copy the file **into** that directory.

Comment: @Simon - that is the best way of learning. mistakes you make help you understand things. Others telling you everything - doesn't help too much.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did. By the way, I'm using grails 2.1.1 and Netbeans 7.2.1

Comment: I agree, but the Grails docs dont help. If I had easy to access docs I'd be fine.

Comment: Anyway, here is what I'm doing now :-   def f = request.getFile("filewav")
      
       String thename = f.fileItem.name
            
       String destfile = "images/wavs/" + thename
   
       def webrootDir = servletContext.getRealPath("/")

       File fileDest = new File(webrootDir,destfile)
       
       f.transferTo(fileDest)

Comment: and the error I'm getting is Grails_Apps\c3i\web-app\images\wavs\30649-PG2.wav (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: I am confused now. It should work. my own code:  `def f = request.getFile('myfile');
        def webrootDir = servletContext.getRealPath("/"); //app directory
        File fileDest = new File(webrootDir,"xmls/");
        def xmlFile = new File(fileDest, "settings.xml");

        f.transferTo(xmlFile);`

Comment: Got it.  You are creating an additional object, of type File, in the line def xmlFile = new File (fileDest, "settings.xml").  I was missing that step!  Many thanks for your help. I think I'm there now.

Comment: Great. When You finish, i'd appreciate if You accepted my answer.